# What is the best way to manage large data using Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have different location information of same companies in the same format as show below, in different excel sheets of a workbook. But based on the requirement I need to create sheets containing above data but in different format i.e. sometimes need to merge the cells of newly developed sheet or setup same data in transpose format for selected location.

All my tables are of same format as given in below example table

```
            INFORMATION OF CORPORATE OFFICES (FOR EXAMPLE)
          A         B               C             D 
     COMPANY    LOCATION 1      LOCATION 2    LOCATION 3
     --------------------------------------------------------
1     co1         10             12            14
2     co2         10             12            14
3     co3         10             12            14
4     co4         10             12            14
```

I have sound knowledge of excel formulas but request expert opinion to manage/reformate my tables to workout efficiently.

Comment: Can you use a database?  Excel tends to get unwieldy in the case of many worksheets with a lot of data in each.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot setup a database at this pc that's why looking for experts opinion here

Comment: @Mr.Khan You should use database.  `Access` is one of the databases you could consider.  The other one is `Sqlite3`.

Comment: Define large. How many rows, columns and tables

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz there must be 50 rows and 8-10 columns (including the A-Company column) in each sheet.

Comment: @Mr.Khan Both `Access` and `Sqlite 3` are free.  Since you are using `Excel`, you 
 should try `Access` first.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a large dataset, of course a database like Access would be better fit for the job. Would need to be more specific about the transformation requirements and the expected growth of records to give a more accurate advice.

Comment: @PaichengWu sorry i have mistake in my previous comment in above i.e. please understood as "unfortunately I can NOT use have/install database at PC."

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Since I have limitation on installing database at my system therefore, please suggest if the growth of records is not as much frequent however i have 6 sheets with 80 rows (name wise) & 6 columns in each, at present. The transformation requirement may include merging of specific values from different sheets (which are integers) based on selected rows (company name). Yet sometimes i need data in transpose format to make it understandable.

Comment: So total records would be= 6 x 80 x 6? 2880? If this is correct. This is perfectly manageable in Excel. Depending on what version you’re using, Power Query is a good option to Extract, Transform and Load your records.